# Where is that folder /etc/apache2/sites-available on mac os yosemite?

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, osx-yosemite

I found /etc/apache2/ , but there is not the folder: sites-available

I need do that config:

In your "apache2/sites-available/" directory edit default as below

```
<Directory /var/www/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              allow from all
              XSendFilePath / 
</Directory>
```

How can I resolve that on Mac OS yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this configuration directly to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

If you need `sites-available` directory, you can make it under `/etc/apache2/` and then add `Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/*` directive to your `httpd.conf`.